# Enlarge image through mouseover using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, mouseover

As part of an assignment I have to enlargen an image using JavaScript through a mouseover. When the image is enlarged it shouldn't move any of the other elements on the page however. When the mouse is moved from the image, it should restore back to the original size.

This is the code that I have so far but it just seems to do absolutely nothing.

```
function imageEnlarge() {

 document.getElementById('1').style.height=100%;
 document.getElementById('1').style.width=100%;
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
 }

function imageReset()   { 

 document.getElementById('1').style.height=80%;
 document.getElementById('1').style.width=80%;
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
}

<img src="home2.jpg" class="homeimage" alt="View of a beach"
                 id="1" onmouseover="imageEnlarge();" onmouseout="imageReset();"
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong. The feedback from my teachers hasn't been the best so I am at a complete loss where to go on this.

Comment: You're probably getting a syntax error from ` document.getElementById('1').style.height=100%;`, because it should be the string `"100%"`, not just `100%`.

Comment: I think that might have been the problem! Changed it to speech marks and it's working as it should, just need to sort the formatting of the image out. Thank you!

Comment: enlarge to what? try zoom property in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this code

```js
function imageEnlarge() {
 document.getElementById('1').style.height="100%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.width="100%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
 }
function imageReset() {

 document.getElementById('1').style.height="80%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.width="80%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
 }
```

Comment: Yeah that has solved my issue, just missed out the speech marks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Any of the parent for this  tag should be having fixed px values for width/height.

Can you check if you have set the width/height for the parent anywhere on the page.

Comment: I used percentages in the CSS, set the image to a width of 80%.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example. I dont think percentage width will help you with position:absolute

Comment: I'm sorry I don't even know what jsfiddle is, I'm literally a beginner with JavaScript. But yeah I've taken the position:absolute out anyway and it's sort of fixed the formatting issues I was having after.